# Rails head style like in ZendFramework

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zend-framework, styles, head

Is it possible to do something similar (ZendFramework) but in rails?

```
<?php $this->headStyle()->captureStart() ?>
body {
    background-color: <?php echo $this->bgColor ?>;
}
<?php $this->headStyle()->captureEnd() ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can `<header><%=yield :header%></header>` in application.html.erb at header, now suppose you want to add some style at header in any other page of application you can do this via `<%= content_for :head do %><style> background-color: <%= somecolor %><% end %>`

I am not php user so i don't know about zend but i hope  this will solve your issue

Comment: Is there a way to call it from the controller?

Comment: search on this site http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content_for-method for "content_for"

Comment: No yo have to place into views,it's not ideal to suits for MVC kind for architecture.View logic should be into views,you can use presenter or draper